Request failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ih1-das-pr-1wp.azure-devices.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
Request
failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ih1-das-pr-1wp.azure-devices.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /devices/R0664654-1WP/messages/events/?api-version-2018-86-30
(Caused by NewConnectionError ('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa0696390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))
I tried to connect to the Azure IoT Hub to send messages but encountered a "No route to host" error. I expected a successful connection, but it failed after multiple retries, likely due to network issues or firewall settings.

Can you please share your code in text format.

I tried using the sample code with the REST API you provided in your question and received the same error, as shown below:

I referred to the documentation on sending device events via REST API to Azure IoT Hub.
Additionally, I consulted the documentation on generating shared access signatures for Azure IoT Hub.
Below is the Python code to send telemetry data to Azure IoT Hub using the REST API.

import requests
import json

iot_hub_name = 'AzureIotHubName.azure-devices.net' 
device_id = 'AzureDeviceId'  
api_version = '2020-03-13'

sas_token = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=...'

url = f'https://{iot_hub_name}/devices/{device_id}/messages/events?api-version={api_version}'

payload = {
    "Temperature": 54  
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': sas_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 204:
        print("Telemetry data sent successfully! (204 No Content)")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send telemetry data. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Response: {response.text}")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")







Output:

The az iot hub monitor-events command is used to monitor device-to-cloud messages (telemetry) sent to an IoT Hub. You can run the following command in the Azure CLI to monitor events in real time:
 az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name `IoTHubName` --output json



